# chrome.management.getSelf is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to know what are the extensions used in my chrome. So I got the solution that to use chrome.management.getSelf() as it can use without management permission in the manifest.json file.

But still If I run it in the console of chrome, it say Cannot read property 'getSelf' of undefined.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Console of a webpage? It's a different context so of course it didn't work.

Comment: So I need to create a html page with script inside?

Comment: can u create a sample code in jsfiddle

Comment: See [extensions architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). The management API can be used in an internal page script of your extension such as event/background/options page or the toolbar popup. It cannot be used in a webpage context so jsfiddle won't help.